# How to show childs of certain custom post type in option list?

Tags: php

I have a custom post type and each post in this custom post type has many childs. I have a code that show every child that is child of the parent in child's page. (parent: post 1 , childs: sub1-post, sub2-post. in sub1-post shows the sub1-post and sub2-post title and permalink)
the code is:

```
<?php
if ( $post->post_parent ) {
    $children = wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
        'echo'     => 0,
        'post_type' => 'mycustom'
    ) );
} else {
    $children = wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        'echo'     => 0,
        'post_type' => 'mycustom'
    ) );
}

if ( $children ) : ?>
    <ul>
        
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Above code works perfect. now i want this code to show the list of children in a select and option mode.
Like:

```
<select>
<option>sub1-post</option>
<option>sub2-post</option>
</select>
```

But i want to echo dynamically. (like `echo $children` but in options).

Hope described well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ***wp_dropdown_pages*** instead of ***wp_list_pages*** . 
This function does almost the same, but returns a dropdown, instead of list items. (do not need to echo select opening and closing tags separately)

```
if ( $post->post_parent ) {

   $children = wp_dropdown_pages( array(
        'name'      => 'your-name' // paste field name here
        'child_of'  => $post->post_parent,
        'post_type' => 'mycustom',
        'echo' => 0
   ));

} else {

   $children = wp_dropdown_pages( array(
        'name'      => 'your-name' // paste field name here
        'child_of'  => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'mycustom',
        'echo' => 0
   ));

}

if( $children ):
    echo $children;
endif;
```

Hope you already know that select is a form element and it keeps post id as option value, so you need to solve this manually if you want to redirect users to selected page id. (Code is not tested)

[wp_dropdown_pages Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_pages/)